# FindFirstFile Not working with Wild cards

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am trying to use the `FindFirstFile` function to traverse through all of my `.txt` files, but I am getting `INVALID_VALUE_HANDLE` error when I try it, here is my function:

```
int search(LPSTR lpszPath)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA WFD;
    HANDLE hSearch;
    CHAR szFilePath[MAX_PATH + 1];
    PathCombine(szFilePath, lpszPath, "*.txt");
    hSearch = FindFirstFile(szFilePath,&WFD);

    if(hSearch == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Error Handle Value\n");
    }

    while (FindNextFile(hSearch,&WFD))
    {
        if(strcmp(WFD.cFileName,"..") && strcmp(WFD.cFileName,"."))
        {

            if(WFD.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                PathCombine(szFilePath, lpszPath, WFD.cFileName);
                search(szFilePath);
            }
            else
            {
                PathCombine(szFilePath, lpszPath, WFD.cFileName);
                printf("%s\n",szFilePath);
        }
    }
}
 FindClose(hSearch);
 return 0;
```

I think the problem comes from the wildcard, any suggestions?

Comment: what is the value of lpszPath

Comment: it is called like this search("L:\\Program Files"); so it is L:\\Program Files

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` return?

Comment: It returns ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND 2 (0x2)

Comment: Well, I'm sure you don't have any .txt file stored in c:\program files.

Comment: yes I have dude, it did not even try to search in the directories it will crash before it even get there.

Comment: Once you solve that problem, you will have an additional problem. The code as written will find all *.txt files except for the first one. You do a FindFirstFile() and do nothing with the results before proceeding to FindNextFile() which will return the second *.txt file since FindFirstFile() already returned the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine that the problem is that this will only find objects that match `*.txt`. You are wanting a recursive search that descends into directories. But it will only descend into directories that match `*.txt`.

For a recursive search like this you have to enumerate all the directories without the `*.txt` wildcard. It may be easier to do the wildcard testing yourself.

So change the code to:

```
PathCombine(szFilePath, lpszPath, "*");
```

and test each file individually for the extension `.txt`.

As others have pointed out, you are failing to check the first file that is found. You must move the `FindNextFile` to the end of the loop.

Comment: Yes I wanted all files which match *.txt, so how can I fix it?

Comment: Search for matches to `*` and then test the extension yourself. Your problem at the moment is that the only directories that can be returned have to match `*.txt` and I'm prepared to bet that exactly zero do so.

Comment: Or perform two searches in each directory. First a `*.txt` search to look for text files, then a `*` search to get the subdirectories for recursion. (`FindExSearchLimitToDirectories` may help with the second search.)

Comment: @Raymond Yes that is probably more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

**CORRECTION:** sorry i used it only in the unicode version. So David is right it works with ANSI characters as well. In this case my guess is, that the path you concatenating is not valid. Maybe you didn't escape the backslash properly e.g. "c:\test\*.txt"

the problem is not the wildcards but the wrong character type. In order to something like this you need to use wide character strings.

look at [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/4d0b9587-8294-48ef-ba53-8e1e7373f59e/) for an example

Comment: Er, that's not true. ANSI versions of FindFirstFile work fine.

Comment: backslash is put on by PathCombine.

Answer (score 1):

So you call `FindFirstFile` and without processing the result you are calling `FindNextFile` again for next file? I am sure you wanted this first result too.